# Leray-Hirsch analogue of algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I want to use a Leray-Hirsch analogue of algebraic geometry to construct the chern classes.  I am not sure how to prove the statement.  Suppose that $E$ is a locally free sheaf of rank $r$ on $X$.  I want to show that if $P(E)$ is the associated projection, then $A(P(E))$ is a free $A(X)$ module generated by $1, z, ..., z^{r-1}$ where $z$ is the first Chern class.  How does one prove this statement?  I want to use this statement to construct the chern classes.  A good reference would be great.  Or an answer or partial answer.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Look at Hirzebruch's *Topological Methods in Algebraic Geometry*, Bott and Tu's *Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology*, among others.

Comment: You mean an algebraic geometry analogue of Leray-Hirsch?

Comment: Yes I do mean that.